# Doubt regarding second quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, second-quantization

In Schwartz it is stated that second quantization can be viewed as modes having energy given by the relation $E=\hbar\omega$ and then considering each mode as simple harmonic oscillator. So my doubt is the energy corresponding to $n\hbar\omega$ can be viewed in following two ways. We operate creation operator on vacuum $n$ times for the state of $\omega$ frequency or we operated just once with the creation operator corresponding to $n\omega$ frequency. So the way to differentiate between these two state is only by measuring the corresponding frequency or wavelength whichever is more convenient. Or is there something more subtle about it? Or my whole thought process is wrong because of some misconception?

Comment: Honestly, I don’t understand what is bothering you. Yes, you are correct, $n$-th power of the creation operator introduces $n \omega \hbar$ of energy. So what?

Comment: Then why should one bother of using creation operator more than once when one can get away by operating only once the creation operator of required frequency.

Comment: ah I see it now. Gonna write an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Acting once with a creation operator of frequency $n \omega$ introduces a single particle of energy $n \omega \hbar$.

Acting $n$ times with a creation operator of frequency $\omega$ introduces $n$ particles of energy $\omega \hbar$ each.

Those are two different, orthogonal quantum states. Actually, Fock space of free QFTs decomposes into $n$-particle subspaces for  each positive integer $n$.

But both states are eigenstates of the energy operator (Hamiltonian) with equal eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

A system with $n$ excitations with energy $\hbar\omega$ each (with total energy $n\hbar\omega$) is different from a system with one excitation with energy $\hbar\omega'$, with $\omega'=n\omega$.

This is clear when looking at the two corresponding Hamiltonian, $\hat H = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega}{2}\hat x^2$ and $\hat H' = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega'}{2}\hat x^2$. This is also true for the wave-function corresponding to these two states.